# how to use call back function with onGenerateRoute

Tags: flutter, dart, routes

I'm Working on Project Where there is A screen For viewing the user Profile and another screen for Editing Profile. I'm using `onGenerateRoute` Method for Routing and know I can parse an argument and send it over.

How I can use Call Back Function `ValueChange` with `onGenerateRoute` Method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to the EditingProfile Page and pass the Function as an argument:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/editingprofile", arguments: () {
        print("Function called");
});
```

In the onGenerateRoute pass the argument to the EditingProfile either as constructor param and call the variable directly

```
Route<dynamic>? generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  final args = settings.arguments;

  switch (settings.name) {
    case "/editingprofile":
      return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => EditingPage(settings.arguments as Function));
  }
}

class EditingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  Function callback;
   SecondPage(this.callback, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: OutlinedButton(
        onPressed: (){
          callback.call();
        },
        child: Text("Press me"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

or pass it inside the MaterialPageRoute as settings param and get the function with ModalRoute

```
Route<dynamic>? generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  final args = settings.arguments;

  switch (settings.name) {
    case "/editingprofile":
      return MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: settings,
          builder: (context) => EditingProfile());
  }
}

class EditingPage extends StatelessWidget {
   EditingPage ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Function callback = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Function;
    return Scaffold(
      body: OutlinedButton(
        onPressed: (){
          callback.call();
        },
        child: Text("Press me"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that's exactly what I want :)